# How can I change the notation in chess-python?

Tags: python, python-chess

I am trying to change the notation of the moves, I mean the library returns for example g1f3 and I want to change to Nf3 (algebraic notation).
I try this method but it doesn't work:

```
board.parse_san(move.move)
```

How can I do it? There is any method in the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#chess.Board.san

Here, you can see that given a `board: chess.Board` and a `move: chess.Move`, you can get the SAN representation of your move using `board.san(move)`, returning a `str`.